# How to create a surface on both sides of an extruded circle outline?

Tags: faces, extrude

Hello Blender beginner here,

I have an SVG of a semi circle with cracked edges at hits bottom.
I imported the svg and looking to 3d model it.
I started by extruding it and was looking to start coloring the surface I scribbled in red.
But I realized this circle has no surface, it's just an outline.
I need to first create a face for it and I'm having some trouble figuring out how.
How would I go about about creating a face on the area covered in red scribbles?

I would like to do this in blender without resorting to going back to re-modifying the original svg via illustrator.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Select a loop and press **F** key to create a face...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, however if you are not concerned about n-gons (faces with more than four sides), then the simplest method would be to:

(BEFORE EXTRUDING THE MESH)

- Select your model in Object mode
- Press Tab to enter Edit mode
- Press 1 on the number **row** (not number pad) of your keyboard, to enter Vertex select mode
- Press A to select all vertices
- Press F to 'Fill', which will create a single face using all of the selected vertices.

If you **are** concerned about n-gons, you may need to manually edit this mesh and create your own quad-faces by selecting 4 vertices at a time, and pressing F to fill.

If you are planning to manually create your faces, I would recommend first *merging vertices by distance*. To merge vertices by distance:

- Select your model in Object mode
- Press Tab to enter Edit mode
- Press 1 on the number **row** (not number pad) of your keyboard, to enter Vertex select mode
- Press A to select all vertices
- Press M to Merge by Distance. This will merge any vertices that are close together into a single vertex. You can change the distance threshold using the options menu in the bottom left corner of the screen (after you press 'M').

Merging vertices by distance will help clean up the model and give you fewer faces to create manually, without removing too much detail from the model.

Comment: Thank you, this was it! Something to note though, I did have to make sure I converted the object to mesh though before it go to work.

Comment: Glad it worked :) Thanks for the note.